# Web Service URL is not working in a Website(as a Service Reference)

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services

I am using Visual Studio 2012 to make a Web Service . I have written the code for Web service , but when I try to use it in a new website by adding
it as a Service Reference(by pasting the running URL of Web Service) .It gives the following error:

```
"There was an error downloading 'http://localhost:3849/WebService3/WebService.asmx/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'.
 Unable to connect to the remote server
 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it   127.0.0.1:3849
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved:  'http://localhost:3849/WebService3/WebService.asmx'.
 There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:3849/WebService3/WebService.asmx that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
 Unable to connect to the remote server
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:3849
 If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again."
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

1. try browsing your service url http://*****:3849/WebService3/WebService.asmx/_vti_bin/ListData.svc in browser and see if metadata is available or not
2. Make sure that all parameters to the operations and return types are generics and not .net specific

Comment: you should check using your service url ending with ?wsdl
e.g. www.myservices.com/services.svc?wsdl inorder to check if metadata is available or not

Comment: I have checked , it says it is not available

Comment: One more thing when I use the service URL in same website where I created the Web Service .It works okay!!.But in the different website , It gives the above error.